# ListView with Custom Adapter - IndexOutOfBoundsException when list is empty

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a `List` in which i store some strings that i get from server. I have a custom adapter for the `ListView`. Each item has a TextView and a Switch.

In the onCreate method, the list will be empty and after the data is received from server, i am calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

My query is specific to Switch(or a Checkbox in similar case). Please look at the code below. I will do my best to explain it using quotes.

```
public class DetailDOMActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ListView listview;
   DealofTheMonthAdapter mDealofTheMonthAdapter;
   List<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_dom);
      ....
      ....

      // Clearing the List before getting values from server
      mTitles.clear();

      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

      // If i remove the below 2 lines, 
      // and add them after getting the data from server,
      // everything works fine.

      // My query here is, when the list is empty,
      // and when getCount() in adapter returns 0,
      // why is getView() being called? 
      // Is this the normal behaviour?
      mDealofTheMonthAdapter = new DealofTheMonthAdapter(this);
      listview.setAdapter(mDealofTheMonthAdapter);

      // Gets Values from server and
      // stores them in mTitles List.  
      // At the end notifyDataSetChanged() 
      // is called on the adapter 
      getDataFromServer();
    }   

   private class DealofTheMonthAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    final Context context;

    List<Boolean> mProgress = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public DealofTheMonthAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mProgress.clear();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_detail_dom, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.mSwitch = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch_dom);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTextView.setText(mTitles.get(position));
        holder.mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked)
                    mProgress.set(position, true);
                else
                    mProgress.set(position, false);
            }
        });

        // IndexOutOfBoundsException at the below line
        holder.mSwitch.setChecked(mProgress.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextView;
    ImageView mImageView;
    SwitchCompat mSwitch;
}

}
```

As far as my knowledge goes, getView() will be called depending on the count returned by getCount(). So, when the list is empty, it should return 0 and hence, getView() should not be called.

Can someone please explain me this behaviour? Let me know if you need anything else.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                         at com.xxx.xx.DetailDOMActivity$DealofTheMonthAdapter.getView(DetailDOMActivity.java:285)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1281)
```

Comment: `mProgress` is empty

Comment: @Blackbelt, I know mProgress is empty, but so is mTitles when it is empty. When there is no exception there, why is there an exception for mProgress

Comment: that's the expected behaviour since getCount is checking the size of mTitles.

Comment: @Blackbelt, Ok so when mTitles is empty, will getView() be called? If so why?

Comment: when `getCount()` returns `0`, `getView` is not called.

Comment: @Blackbelt, But, that is what is happening now, right? If not, please let me know where i am going wrong? mTitles is empty but getView() is getting called.

Comment: Ok, i get it, it's getting called after getting values from server.. Thanks, my bad. I should set mProgress values to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by `mProgress` which is empty while `mTitles` is not. Dealing with multiple collections on `ListView` can be tricky, since you have always to make sure that all the collections have at least `getCount()`'s size. That's of course possible, but is error prone. What you can do is to wrap all the information around a Model class. E.g.

```
 public class MyModel {
    public String name;
    public boolean isChecked
 }
```

and change from `List<String> mTitles` to `List<MyModel> mTitles`. This way you can deal with only one collection, and easily retrieve and change the property of the the item at position